# Python gspread, how to populate google sheet, dictionaries within list

Tags: python, dictionary, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I tried looking at the answers of similar questions but wasn't able to get the code working. I'm having trouble understanding how to populate gspread of similar dictionaries within a list.

Below is my data structure that I want to export:

```
    sheet_data = [{
                "timestamp": "09-04-2019",
                "value": "10.0",
                "company_name": "Xbox",
                "product": "Buy"
                },
                {
                "timestamp": "09-03-2019",
                "value": "2.0",
                "company_name": "something",
                "product": "Sell"
        }]
```

Below is what I've tried and works now. My remaining question is, I am manually inputting the cell_range = worksheet.range('A2:D3'), how can I do it so it updates the sheet to whatever cell is available with the given data. Since the amount of data I have in sheet_data will change in future updates.

```
header = ['timestamp', 'value', 'company_name', 'product']
        worksheet.add_rows(len(sheet_data))
        cell_range = worksheet.range('A2:D3')
        flat_sheet_data = []
        for row in sheet_data:
            for column in header:
                flat_sheet_data.append(row[column])
        for i, cell in enumerate(cell_range):
            cell.value = flat_sheet_data[i]
        worksheet.update_cells(cell_range)
```

link to image of what I want to accomplish on spreedsheet using above data structure:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQLEI.png

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? About `my data structure that I want to export:`, do you want to retrieve the values from Google Spreadsheet as an object of `sheet_data`? But in your script, it seems that the range of "A2:C10" is updated. So can I ask you about your goal? By the way, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet and sample result values you expect? I think that it will help users think of the solution. Of course, please remove your personal information. By the way, have you already been able to get and put values for Spreadsheet using gspread?

Comment: @tanaike yes I can already put values on the spreedsheet, with my above script it populates certain rows with 'x'.  I want to update, or push the above data structure into google sheet. I also attached an image of what I want to do.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. You have already been able to use gspread. And you want to put `sheet_data` to Spreadsheet. I could understand like this. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, I have one more question. When I saw your image and `sheet_data`, it seems that the headers of Spreadsheet and the keys of `sheet_data` are different. How about this?

Comment: @tanaike yes, you understand everything correctly. The headers are different, I'd like to keep the headers I already defined in the googlesheet but if need be I can work with the Key's  from sheet_data as headers .

Comment: Why would you assign `row` (i.e. a whole dictionary representing a row) to cell.value? Shouldn't you instead `cell.value = row['value']` and just iterate over the row that needs `value`? Then do the same for the other rows, instead of doing the whole block at once. Or, alternatively, simply have 4 assignment statements, assigning the correct value to the correct cell in order - but that'll be a bit messy.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying and additional information, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: @AMC I still have one issue with my code that I wrote above. It works but I manually have to set the `cell_range = worksheet.range('A4:D5') ` variable when I do updates. How can I push dictionary updates without knowing the cell_range of what it should be in Google sheet.

Comment: @zstar Oh, so you want to automatically calculate the dimensions/shape of the area so that all the data fits? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @AMC yes, you got it perfectly! If you can show me with my code I already wrote above(the code works but the dimensions/shape is hard-coded), then that would be nice! And possibly, making sure that it doesn't overwrite existing data if it exists in the spreedsheet. Since I will regurarly be pushing new updates to sheet_data which will then be pushed to the existing sheet. Is the last part is not possible, no worries, I can figure it out later but the dimensions will be a good start.

Comment: @zstar I doubt I would be able to come up with anything better than the accepted answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to put `sheet_data` to Spreadsheet.
- You have already been able to get and put values using Sheets API with gspread.
- From your headers in the image and keyes of `sheet_data`, "Date", "Company_Name", "Traffic" and "Product" are corresponding to "timestamp", "company_name", "value" and "product", respectively.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Flow:

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Prepare `header_to_key`.
2. Create a list for putting to Spreadsheet.
3. Put the created list using the method of `values_append`.

#### Sample script:

Before you run the script, please set the variables.

```
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1"  # Please set the sheet name.

sheet_data = [{
    "timestamp": "09-04-2019",
    "value": "10.0",
    "company_name": "Xbox",
    "product": "Buy"
}, {
    "timestamp": "09-03-2019",
    "value": "2.0",
    "company_name": "something",
    "product": "Sell"
}]

header_to_key = {
    'Date': 'timestamp',
    'Company_Name': 'company_name',
    'Traffic': 'value',
    'Product': 'product'
}

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)

headers = worksheet.row_values(1)
put_values = []
for v in sheet_data:
    temp = []
    for h in headers:
        temp.append(v[header_to_key[h]])
    put_values.append(temp)
spreadsheet.values_append(sheetName, {'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'}, {'values': put_values})
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that the headers of "Date", "Company_Name", "Traffic" and "Product" are set to the Spreadsheet like your image.

#### Reference:

- [values_append(range, params, body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=append#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_append)

Comment: I was able to solve it a few seconds before I saw this (updated my question with what works for me) but your answer is much much better and it seems that it allows for me to not know the worksheet.range. Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate your time!

Comment: @zstar Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

The below approach worked for me

```
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sh = gc.open_by_url("url of the sheet")
ws = sh.worksheet(ws_title)
records = json.loads(sheet_data)
keys = [str(eachvalue) for eachvalue in records.keys()]
values = [str(eachvalue) for eachvalue in records.values()]
Data =[{'range': 'A1:D1','values': [keys],}, {'range': 'A2:D2','values': [values],}]
ws.batch_update(Data);
```